# serve static folder image using express with loopback 4

Tags: node.js, express, loopbackjs

I'm using express for serving static folder using loopback 4 like

```
 let dir = path.join(directory)
    server.use(express.static(dir));
    server.listen(3001);
```

But my application is running on the 4200 port and server.listen(3001) creates
A new port but i want to do the same on 4200
If i'm giving server.listen(4200) then that not start because its can't run on two server on same port

Is that possible to serve file on existing port

Comment: Two server can't use a port at the same time.

Comment: yes i know so is there any method to serve file on existing port using express ?

Comment: I think you can use `sub-directory`  or even a webserver like `nginx` and set proxy on different `sub-domain`s.

Answer (score 1):

You can add

```
app.use('/static', express.static('public'));
```

to your app main file.

This serves your files in the `public` folder in the `/static` endpoint, so if you have a file `public/hello.jpg` you can use it from `localhost:4200/static/hello.jpg`.

Comment: Well, don't remove that.

Comment: if i wont than  it is suppose to be two app and not will start on same port

Comment: No it won't, `app.use` specifies a middleware to be used on a specific path, in this case `/static`. Please read the [docs](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use).